# i want to combine below two codes

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, gsm

**************************1st code*********************

```cpp
int sensoroutput = 3; // the analog pin connected to the sensor
int sensorinput = A0;
int THRESHOLD = 100;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(A0, INPUT);   // this function is used to declare gsm connected pin as output
}

void loop()
{
    int value = analogRead(sensorinput);  // function to read analog voltage from sensor
    if (value >= THRESHOLD)                    // function to check voltage level from sensor
    {
        digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
        delay(100);
    }
    else
        digitalWrite(3, LOW);
}
```

*********2nd code*************

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial sim800l(0, 1); // RX,TX for Arduino and for the module it's TXD RXD, they should be inverted

#define button1 7 //Button pin, on the other pin it's wired with GND

bool button_State; //Button state

void setup()
{
    pinMode(button1, INPUT_PULLUP); //The button is always on HIGH level, when pressed it goes LOW
    sim800l.begin(9600);   //Module baude rate, this is on max, it depends on the version
    Serial.begin(9600);
    delay(1000);
}

void loop()
{
    button_State = digitalRead(button1);   //We are constantly reading the button State

    if (button_State == LOW) {            //And if it's pressed
        Serial.println("Button pressed");   //Shows this message on the serial monitor
        delay(200);                         //Small delay to avoid detecting the button press many times

        SendSMS();                          //And this function is called
    }

    if (sim800l.available()) {            //Displays on the serial monitor if there's a communication from the module
        Serial.write(sim800l.read());
    }
}

void SendSMS()
{
    Serial.println("Sending SMS...");               //Show this message on serial monitor
    sim800l.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");                   //Set the module to SMS mode
    delay(100);
    sim800l.print("AT+CMGS=\"+918707578617\"\r");  //Your phone number don't forget to include your country code, example +212123456789"
    delay(500);
    sim800l.print("SIM800l is working");       //This is the text to send to the phone number, don't make it too long or you have to modify the SoftwareSerial buffer
    delay(500);
    sim800l.print((char)26);// (required according to the datasheet)
    delay(500);
    sim800l.println();
    Serial.println("Text Sent.");
    delay(500);

}
```

Comment: So... what's stopping you combining those two codes?

Comment: what is your question? ... this is a Q&A site ... a specific, answerable question is required